# Cannot get didSelectRowAtIndexPath to register a click

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, didselectrowatindexpath

I've build a version of DrWhat's [autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885438/getting-autocomplete-to-work-in-swift), but I cannot get the clicks to register within the TableView.

I'm just trying to print a line to confirm at this point.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        println("Cell was clicked")
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the `delegate`?

Comment: I was having a similar issue..............i hope this will help....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217789/didselectrowatindexpath-called-after-long-press

Answer (score 1):

verify if you have assaigned the delegate and datasource for the tableview.
you have several toutorials and simple explanations to do it.

have a look at it for an instance.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_ui_elements_tableview.htm