# didSelectRowAtIndexPath called after long press

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `uitableview` right below a `uitextfield` that populates similar strings in a `uitableview cell`.
The items get populated. However the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets called after long press

My `UITableView` (is embedded in UIScrollView) 
`- didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` only being called after long press on custom cell

My view hierarchy:

- UIScrollView  (outerscroll)

  - Some other views and buttons
  - UITexfield
  - UITableView (tableView)

My Code

```
class MyViewController:  BaseViewController , UITextFieldDelegate , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {



@IBOutlet weak var autocompleteTableView: UITableView!
var pastUrls = ["Men", "Women", "Cats", "Dogs", "Children","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","a","aa","aaa"]
var autocompleteUrls = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var image_view_seacrh_ifsc: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = true

    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = true
    autocompleteTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    autocompleteTableView.allowsSelection = true
    autocompleteTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true

    autocompleteTableView.hidden = true




    super.hideKeyboard()
    super.showNavigationBarBackButton()

    let gesture_search_ifsc = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action_Search_Ifsc:")
    gesture_search_ifsc.delegate = self
    gesture_search_ifsc.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    image_view_seacrh_ifsc.userInteractionEnabled = true
    image_view_seacrh_ifsc.addGestureRecognizer(gesture_search_ifsc)


}




func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    autocompleteUrls.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    for curString in pastUrls
    {
        var myString:NSString! = curString as NSString

        var substringRange :NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)

        if (substringRange.location  == 0)
        {
            autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
        }
    }

    autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
    //autocompleteTableView.hidden = false
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocompleteUrls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell: AutoBankCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AutoBankCell") as! AutoBankCell

    cell.label.text = self.autocompleteUrls[indexPath.row]
    //cell.lbl.text = self.autocompleteUrls[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    self.bank_name.text = self.autocompleteUrls[indexPath.row]

    self.autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = true
    self.autocompleteTableView.hidden = true
}


}
```

My `UItableView` gets populated and works properly when not embedded in `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Why are you adding gesture recognizer on tableview?

Comment: I was just trying to see if that would work..........But gesture recognizer on UITableView did not work.......... Could you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `uiview` in your `scroll view` and add every elements in that `uiview` like your `tableView,textfield,views and buttons` etc.

So, that view works as container view.

Make sure that you are setting proper constraints if you are using `autolayout`.

Second thing remove unnecessary gesture recognizer `implicitly` which is not required.

Tableview have scroll enable by default so not need to set it true again. (it's not affect your issue btw!!)

So remove unnecessary configuration and make proper setup and your issue will be solved i think.

Comment: @Lion...........what you said worked kind of.........But didSelectRowAtIndexPath: only being called after long press on custom cell

Comment: have you added long tap gesture on tableview or row or cell ?

Comment: No I have not added a long tap gesture