# Add auto complete to UITextField inside UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I followed the suggestion here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32948918/5447089

But it seems to work when a Text Field is inside `UIViewController`. In my case the TF is inside `UITableViewCell` and table with suggestions doesn't appear when there is some data for auto completion.

Also `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called. Other delegate methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection` work normally.

What can be the reason for this?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddElemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    var autocompleteTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0,80,320,120), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

    var elements = [“Beer”, “Bear”, “Park”, “Pad”]
    var autocompleteElements = [String]()

    var currentElem: Elem!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        myTextField.delegate = self
        autocompleteTableView.delegate = self
        autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self
        autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = true
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = true

        myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AddElemTableViewCell.didChangeText(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
    }


    func didChangeText(textField:UITextField) {
        autocompleteTableView.hidden = false
        let substring = (myTextField.text! as NSString)
        searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring as String)


    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
    {
        autocompleteElements.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        for curString in elements
        {
            let myString:NSString! = curString as NSString

            let substringRange :NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring,options: [.CaseInsensitiveSearch])

            if (substringRange.location  == 0)
            {
                autocompleteElements.append(curString)
            }
        }

        autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == myTextField {
            if (textField.text!.characters.count > 0) {
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

                let entityElement = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("element", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

                let element = element(entity: entityElement!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

                element.name = textField.text!

                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let saveError = error as NSError
                    print(saveError)
                }

                textField.text! = ""
                textField.placeholder = “add new element”
                self.endEditing(true)

            }
        }
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return autocompleteElements.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier"
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default , reuseIdentifier: autoCompleteRowIdentifier)
        let index = indexPath.row as Int

        cell.textLabel!.text = autocompleteElements[index]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        myTextField.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
    }


}
```

Comment: You'll really need to post all your code. There are an infinite number of ways to make a programming bug. :-)

Comment: @BaseZen I edited the code. `AddElemTableViewCell` is a Dynamic Prototype cell.