# Add Auto Complete to TextField in Existing TableViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autocomplete, swift3

I'm new to IOS programming and for StackOverflow so please consider it :)

I have a TableViewController with one textField at the top of the page and I would like to add the auto complete option for it.

I searched the web for this option and i found this thread: [Getting autocomplete to work in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885438/getting-autocomplete-to-work-in-swift)

I saw that in order to add this abillity I have to add another TableView and then configure a cell.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to add the extra table view on the TableViewController (with static cells) to have this auto complete work.

If it does possible, how can I create the cell identifier programmatically?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The reference you have given has taken a `UIViewController`, hence he needs to add extra `UITableView`, but in your case you have taken `UITableViewController` which has inbuilt `UITableView`. So You can use that table view. just get reference by writing `self.tableView`.

For your second question how to configure tale cell, look at this tutorial
https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Hope it helps ...