# How to have suggestions come up when filling in TextField?

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield

I am new to IOS development. I am trying to add simple TextField for entering Occupation. I would like to show the user some matching suggestions as they user type (from a set of occupations that I already have). 
This is a very common usecase. Is there a idiomatic ways of doing this? In Android there is an `AutoCompleteTextView` in the standard view library which takes in an array of suggestions during initalization. I could not find anything similar in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some 3rd party libraries available for Auto complete text field
but
the best and easy approach from my perspective is to use UITextField and at bottom add UITableview. So the concept is when you type any character in textfield you need to filter some data from tableview and reload tableview

Check the below link you can get the suitable answer from here...

[Getting autocomplete to work in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885438/getting-autocomplete-to-work-in-swift)

Comment: Do you have any library recommendation?

Comment: I am not damn sure but you can try this one
https://cocoapods.org/pods/CCAutocomplete